# Report Not Running on Selections in CRM Dynamics Online (Greyed Out)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Please assist me, I am trying to run reports on selected records in a CRM Dynamics view, but they are greyed out as shown in the image below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How many records have you got selected?

Comment: I am selecting only 15 items inside a selection r let's say the selection consist of 15 items

Comment: Have you got pre-filtering enabled on those reports?

Comment: Yes , the CRMAF_ Filtering is on and, this report work so well everywhere else just except on Selections